# How do I create a scheduled task to connect to another wifi connection

Tags: windows-8.1, scheduled-tasks

I’m running Windows 8.1 and would like to set up a scheduled task to connect to another known wifi connection and then run the required scripts that I need. I’m aware of making a scheduled task run only if it is already connected to a specific connection, but is there a way that I can get the scheduled task to actually make that connection for me?

For example,

1. I am connected to Wifi spot A at 8:50AM
2. It becomes 9:00AM
3. The schedueled task runs and connects me to Wifi spot B
4. Runs the required scripts
5. End Task
6. (Bonus if the task can connect me back to Wifi spot A after running the scripts, though)

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find a  way around this by including a few lines in my .bat file

I used

> netsh wlan connect name=wifiname

Before the rest of my script to connect to the required network. Then I used the same line at the end of it to connect back to the original network I was on. This then gets schedueled at 9AM and does it all in one hit.